# Almost all the http APIs return a 502 bad gateway error after adding a CDN

Tags: nginx, cdn, 502-error, 502

I just added my website to a CDN provider https://www.qiniu.com/en. Then I realised that almost all my http APIs (https://www.funfun.ink/httpOnly...) returned a 502 bad gateway error. Additionally, https://47.52.108.146/1/#/home did not work anymore, it returned a 502 bad gateway error as well.

Probably something is wrongly set up in the CDN provider, does anyone know what may be that?

Here is the console of https://www.funfun.ink/1/#/home

[image]

Here is the console of https://www.funfun.ink/1/#/edit/

[image]

Here is the nginx block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name funfun.ink www.funfun.ink;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name funfun.ink www.funfun.ink;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/1530230026231.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/1530230026231.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~* ^/\b(?!1|js|socket.io|monaco-editor|libs|dist|fonts|javascripts|formatter|ui|css|stylesheets|htmls|imgs|static|httpOnly|tmp|uploads)\w+\b/? {
        rewrite .* /1/#$request_uri redirect;
    }

    location ~* ^/1/\b(?!#|auth)\w+\b/? {
        rewrite ^/1/(.*[.]js)$ https://www.funfun.ink/dist/$1 redirect;
        rewrite ^/1/(.*[^.][^j][^s])$ https://www.funfun.ink/1/#/$1 redirect;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 /home;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`proxy_pass httpS://127.0.0.1:3000`... Are you sure that you can connect to the localhost (127.0.0.1) via SSL?

`proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;` - in this line, you already forward the scheme to the upstream server. So, the application (or the upstream server) should be smart enough to identify the scheme being used / forwarded.

So, the `proxy_pass` directive should be `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000`.